# How can I change haarcascade_profileface.xml's direction?

Tags: xml, haar-classifier

[This classifier](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_profileface.xml) detects only faces which are looking left and i need a face classifier that detects faces which are looking right. Can i do this with making changes on its xml file or any open source file available? How can i do this? I don't want to dealing with cascade trainers, please.

Answer (score 0):

You basically flip the image before passing it to the classifier. Here the fancy Python example:)

```
image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
```